# Cucumber: Best practice for writing cucumber steps that are shared among different feature sets?

Tags: cucumber

I'm new to cucumber as a testing suite. I notice that as I build out feature and write steps. Lets say as a bad example (since I'm working backwards) I write a bunch of stuff for creating posts that require a User.

I end up writing a bunch of User based steps (log in process etc) in a feature set mainly dedicated to Post features.

Is it best practice to later move steps into the appropriate feature set as tests get more complicated and features get added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two parts to consider here.

- Organize scenarios so they make sense. That is to place them in the proper `feature` files.
- Organize the implementation of the steps so they make sense. That is, implement the steps in the proper source code files.

Your question boils down to "What makes sense in my context?".

It depends on your stakeholders, do they want all user facing scenarios in the same feature file or are they more interested in business facing scenarios that sometimes involve users? Organize the scenarios so your stakeholders are happy.

How should you organize the steps then? It depends on your developers and your ability to share state between step definitions that are implemented in different source code files.

My approach would probably be to start out small and let the suite grow. This would initially not involve sharing state between different classes during runtime. When the suite feels to large to handle, divide it in two parts that are as coherent as you can make them. When this gets to large, repeat the division again. You will, hopefully, end up with something that works well in your context.

Remember that your context and your product is unique. It probably deserves a unique solution that your team feel they can maintain.

Understandability and therefore manintainability is the most important property I can think of regarding the executable specification you are building.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. This is a personal project for learning Cucumber and some new rails features along the way. Your part about dividing parts until it becomes coherent is what I started doing before I asked this question to see what was best. Thanks again for the input.